# The range of the angular coordinates in (asymptotically) AdS$_5$ spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, coordinate-systems, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

In the papers I’ve seen with GR solutions in (asymptotically) AdS$_5$ spacetimes, when Boyer-Linquist-like coordinates $(t,r,\theta,\phi,\psi)$ are used, the ranges of the angular coordinates is as follows

$$\theta \in [0,\, \pi/2], \quad \phi \in [0,\, 2\pi], \quad \psi \in [0,\, 2\pi].$$

Could someone explain to me where these ranges come from, especially $\theta$?

Comment: Does: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-sphere#Hopf_coordinates answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!